# Static files not loading properly

Tags: django

Things I have done:

1.base template i have provide {% load static %}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
 
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/static/assets/img/apple-icon.png" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'assets/img/favicon.png' %}" >

  <title>
    Al Amal Jewellery - {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </title>

  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Nucleo Icons -->
  <link href="{% static "assets/css/nucleo-icons.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link id="pagestyle" href="{% static "assets/css/soft-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.0.5" %}" rel="stylesheet" />


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
  {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

</head> 
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
  

  {% include "includes/sidebar.html" %}

  <main class="main-content max-height-vh-full h-100">

    {% include "includes/navigation.html" %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

  </main>

  {% include "includes/fixed-plugin.html" %}
  
  {% include "includes/scripts.html" %}  

  <!-- Specific JS goes HERE --> 
  {% block javascripts %}{% endblock javascripts %}

  <script>
    var win = navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1;
    if (win && document.querySelector('#sidenav-scrollbar')) {
      var options = {
        damping: '0.5'
      }
      Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('#sidenav-scrollbar'), options);
    }
  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

2. statics in setting.py based on [Managing Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os, random, string
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # take environment variables from .env.

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
if not SECRET_KEY:
    SECRET_KEY = ''.join(random.choice( string.ascii_lowercase  ) for i in range( 32 ))

# Render Deployment Code
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','localhost', '.ngrok.io', '.ngrok-free.app','alamalcrm.azurewebsites.net','aacrm.azurewebsites.net']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [os.getenv('CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS')]
if not CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS:
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://aacrm.azurewebsites.net/','https://alamalcrm.azurewebsites.net/']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'widget_tweaks',
    'home',
    'sales',
    'purchases',
    'chitty',
    'inventory',
    'wholesaler',
    'accounts',
    'authentication',
    'rest_framework',
    'import_export',
    'django_apscheduler',
    # 'django_extensions',
    'mathfilters',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    'daimond',
    # "debug_toolbar",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)

# Redirect to home URL after login (Default redirects to /accounts/profile/)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "login"


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DB_ENGINE   = os.getenv('DB_ENGINE'   , None)
DB_USERNAME = os.getenv('DB_USERNAME' , None)
DB_PASS     = os.getenv('DB_PASS'     , None)
DB_HOST     = os.getenv('DB_HOST'     , None)
DB_PORT     = os.getenv('DB_PORT'     , None)
DB_NAME     = os.getenv('DB_NAME'     , None)

if DB_ENGINE and DB_NAME and DB_USERNAME:
    DATABASES = { 
      'default': {
        'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.' + DB_ENGINE, 
        'NAME'    : DB_NAME,
        'USER'    : DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASS,
        'HOST'    : DB_HOST,
        'PORT'    : DB_PORT,
        }, 
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_datatables.renderers.DatatablesRenderer',
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework_datatables.filters.DatatablesFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework_datatables.pagination.DatatablesPageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 50,
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_FORMAT = ['%Y-%m-%d']

USE_L10N = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'static'),
)


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Format string for displaying run time timestamps in the Django admin site. The default
# just adds seconds to the standard Django format, which is useful for displaying the timestamps
# for jobs that are scheduled to run on intervals of less than one minute.
# 
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-format for format string
# syntax details.
APSCHEDULER_DATETIME_FORMAT = "N j, Y, f:s a"

# Maximum run time allowed for jobs that are triggered manually via the Django admin site, which
# prevents admin site HTTP requests from timing out.
# 
# Longer running jobs should probably be handed over to a background task processing library
# that supports multiple background worker processes instead (e.g. Dramatiq, Celery, Django-RQ,
# etc. See: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/ for popular options).
APSCHEDULER_RUN_NOW_TIMEOUT = 25  # Seconds
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 10240 

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
# STORAGES = {
#     # ...
#     "staticfiles": {
#         "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
#     },
# }
# INTERNAL_IPS = [
#     # ...
#     "127.0.0.1",
#     # ...
# ]
```

3. my directory

[image: directory]

4. In my inventory.html I provided the

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% block title %} {{page2}} {% endblock title %}

<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block body_class %} g-sidenav-show bg-gray-100 {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="container-fluid py-4">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <!-- Card header -->
          <div class="card-header pb-0">
            <div class="d-lg-flex">
              <div>
                <h5 class="mb-0">{{page2}}</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="ms-auto my-auto mt-lg-0 mt-4">
                <div class="ms-auto my-auto">
                  <a href= {% url 'newinventory' %} class="btn bg-gradient-primary btn-sm mb-0" target="_blank">+&nbsp; New Stock</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm export mb-0 mt-sm-0 mt-1" data-type="csv" type="button" name="button">Export</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body px-0 pb-0">
            <div class="table-responsive" id="div_inventorytable">
              <table class="table table-flush" id="inventorytable">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Karat</th>
                    <th>WT</th>
                    <th>SWT</th>
                    <th>PMC</th>
                    <th>barcode</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for item in object_list %}
                  <tr id="item-{{ item.pk }}">
                    <td>
                      <div class="d-flex">
                        <img class="w-10 ms-3" src="{{item.PhotoDIR.url}}" alt="hoodie" loading="lazy">
                        <h6 class="ms-3 my-auto">{{ item.Name }} - {{ item.Location }}</h6>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ item.K.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.NetWT }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.SWT }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.PMC }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Barcode }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Status }}</td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm">
                      <a href="{% url 'barcodeprintpage' pk=item.pk t='item' %}" target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-original-title="Barcode">
                        <i class="fas fa-barcode text-secondary"></i>
                      </a>
                      {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                      <a href="{% url 'itemupdate' item.id %}" class="mx-3" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-original-title="Edit product">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-edit text-secondary"></i>
                      </a>
                      <a href="#"  data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-original-title="Delete product" onclick="deleteitem('{{item.id}}')">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash text-secondary text-secondary"></i>
                      </a>
                      {% endif %}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>      
            </div>
          </div>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

{% endblock content %}

<!-- Specific JS goes HERE --> 
{% block javascripts %} 
  
  <script src="{% static "assets/js/plugins/datatables.js"  %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static "js/inventory/inventorylist.js" %}"></script>
  {% comment %} <script src="{% static "js/inventory/barcode.js"%}"></script> {% endcomment %}

{% endblock javascripts %}
```

My issues

1. > ‘static’, expected ‘endblock’. Did you forget to register or load this tag? (on the inventory.html )
2. > “GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1” 304 0 (this is on the base html only and 304 means it was already loaded right? )

i am not sure where i made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add {% load static  %} at the top of your template. This will load them. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I did that and it worked but in all the doc in django they dont do that. I looked into  django  official web sites and others( like medium etc )and they dont do that. I was wondering why i cant

Comment: I'm happy to hear it worked, please give the answer a +1 and get the pints in. Good luck